# Pass auto increment variable in request URL and body if HTTP request in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, auto-increment

I am having a endpoint which accepts a auto-increment integer id as part of path param and in request body also there are some keys which accepts that as well.

For example endpoint is `http://foo.bar/{id}`

And body is

```
{
 "someid" : someno+{id passed in url},
 "some world :"fixed string" + "id passed in url"
}
```

I tried using `__counter()` directly in place of my {id}, but its not working and in when debugging found that its not replacing the value and its coming as literal only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add [Counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) and call the reference name you defined wherever you want.

[image]

> Allows the user to create a counter that can be referenced anywhere in the Thread Group

Answer (score 1):

There is [__counter() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) which is generating an incremented number each time it's being called, you can put its declaration into the URL like:

```
${__counter(FALSE,counter)}
```

and the [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) reference into the request body:

```
{
 "someid" : someno+${counter},
 "some world :"fixed string" + "id passed in url"
}
```

[image]

This way you will get an unique incremented number for each call

[image]

More information: [How to Use a Counter in a JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test/)

Comment: Nice explaination

Answer (score 0):

4 years passed, I jmeter changed a little, so let me give another detailed answer:

1.create a test plan
2.create a thread group under this test plan
[image]
3.create a http request under this "thread group"

[image]

4.under this "http request", create a "loop controller"
[image]

5.under this "loop controller", create a "counter"
[image]

6.run this thread group, and check your web app log:

[image]